# How do I request to graphql with header and auth key in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, request, hasura

I have this endpoint and I have to get data but the request do not see my key but its required.

Endpoint: https://sunny-gorilla-88.hasura.app/v1/graphql

x-hasura-admin-secret: `X4Hh7kQrymAVxjnw17S6e7n0PChHGbfhV2AgjqnL50aJG5u78zvcgr0no0cSCtbt`

How can I handle it with react please help. The graphql tutorials not working I tried them all

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have disabled the Hasura console. Now you can access it via CLI
( https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/hasura-cli/install-hasura-cli.html#install-hasura-cli ), check the documentation for reference

https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/migrations/migrations-setup.html#migrations-setup

In order to just run it type this in console

```
hasura init --endpoint https://sunny-gorilla-88.hasura.app/ --admin-secret X4Hh7kQrymAVxjnw17S6e7n0PChHGbfhV2AgjqnL50aJG5u78zvcgr0no0cSCtbt
```

after the project is initialized run

```
hasura conole
```